# Accessing current watermark in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, watermark

Is there any way to access current watermark value in Spark Structured Streaming?

I'd like to process events in their event-time order to find patterns in sequences. To do it I was thinking of using flatMapGroupsWithState and buffer events till the watermark passes (and avoid buffering late events) and process them one-by-one. But I don't know how to access current watermark to do it. Is it event possible in Spark Structure Streaming?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `StreamingQueryProgress` from your `StreamingQuery` object:

```
query.lastProgress()/recentProgress()
```

It will contain an `eventTime.watermark` field

something like:

```
{
  "id" : "eb7202da-9e60-4983-89fc-e1251aebf89d",
  "runId" : "969555bd-6189-4b70-a101-3b5917cea965",
  "name" : "my-query",
  "timestamp" : "2023-01-05T16:46:43.372Z",
  "batchId" : 6,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "latestOffset" : 7,
    "triggerExecution" : 7
  },
  "eventTime" : {
    "watermark" : "2023-01-01T09:44:11.000Z"
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ {
    "operatorName" : "stateStoreSave",
...etc
}
```